# c# How to change string from Form 1 from button click on Form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Zombie Survival RPG Game and I want to make it so when I press a button (The move button from the "MainGame" form) that all the strings from the "Look-Out" form change to whatever I want. (When move button is clicked, the player can see different Items then the last time.)

Here is my code:

Form 1 (button move click)

```
 public void btn_move_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (locationArea == 165 && locationDistrict == 1 && locationSection == 1 )
            {

            }
            //SURVIVAL
            if (thirst < 0)
            {
                thirst = 0;
            }
            if (hunger < 0)
            {
                hunger = 0;
            }
            if (thirst == 0)
            {
                tmr_health.Start();
            }

            if (hunger == 0)
            {
                tmr_health.Start();
            }
            //BEAT GAME
            if (gameprogress == 0 && difficultynormal == 1)
            {
                tmr_health.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Normal win text", "Congratulations!");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (gameprogress == 0 && difficultyhardcore == 1)
            {
                tmr_health.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Hardcore win text", "Congratulations!");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (gameprogress == 0 && difficultyinsane == 1)
            {
                tmr_health.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Insane win text", "Congratulations!");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (gameprogress == 0 && difficultyimpossible == 1)
            {
                tmr_health.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Impossible win text", "Congratulations!");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (rb_crouching.Checked == true)
            {
                timehour = timehour + 1;
            }

            gameprogress = gameprogress - 1;
            //Int to Label
            lbl_gameprogressvalue.Text = gameprogress.ToString();
            lbl_locationDistrictValue.Text = locationDistrict.ToString();
            lbl_timeHour.Text = timehour.ToString();
            lbl_locationSectionValue.Text = locationSection.ToString();
            lbl_locationAreaValue.Text = locationArea.ToString();
            lbl_ingamehungervalue.Text = hunger.ToString();
            lbl_ingamethirstvalue.Text = thirst.ToString();

            //STAT DEPLEATION
            if (rb_walking.Checked == true)
            {
                thirst = thirst - 10;
                hunger = hunger - 5;
            }
            if (rb_jogging.Checked == true)
            {
                thirst = thirst - 15;
                hunger = hunger - 10;
            }
            if (rb_sprinting.Checked == true)
            {
                thirst = thirst - 20;
                hunger = hunger - 15;
            }
            if (rb_crouching.Checked == true)
            {
                thirst = thirst - 5;
                hunger = hunger - 5;
            }

            timehour = timehour + 1;
            locationSection = locationSection + 1;
            if (timehour > 12 && lbl_timeEnding.Text == "AM")
            {
                timehour = 1;
                lbl_timeEnding.Text = PM;
            }

            if (lbl_timeEnding.Text == PM && timehour > 12)
            {
                lbl_timeEnding.Text = "AM";
                timehour = 1;
                dateday = dateday + 1;
                dayssurvived = dayssurvived + 1;
                lbl_dayssurvivedvalue.Text = dayssurvived.ToString();
                lbl_dateDay.Text = dateday.ToString();




            }
            if (locationSection == 11)
            {
                locationSection = 0;
                locationDistrict = locationDistrict + 1;
            }

            if (locationDistrict == 6)
            {
                locationDistrict = 0;
                locationArea = locationArea + 1;
            }

        }
```

Form 2 (data that needs to be changed)

```
 public partial class Look_out : Form
    {
        string item1 = "";
        string item2 = "";
        string item3 = "";
        string item4 = "";
        string item5 = "";
        public Look_out()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            item1 = "Butterfly Knife";
            item2 = "";
            //String to Label
            lbl_item1.Text = item1;
            lbl_item2.Text = item2;
            lbl_item1.Visible = true;

            if (item1 == "")
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to write methods in the `Look_out` class to accept the strings and do what you wanted with them

Comment: You also should consider using a [switch statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) instead of many nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make a propertie ex:

```
public string YourString
{
   { get; set; }
},
```

so pass value for it after you create a Form Look_out

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the below code:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.theVariable = textBox1.Text;
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string theVariable //This is your method to pass the string to the new form (Form2)
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
            set { textBox1.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```